How to link a calculated field built to a parameter in Tableau?
I have created a calculated field in Tableau as below and it is giving the desired output when pulled as a row value in tabular format.
 Designer_new = IF CONTAINS(TRIM([Role]),"Designer") THEN [Owner] ELSE 'NA' END

However, when I link this to a parameter as below, the 'Designer' value selection only reads NA in the output:
    IF [Parameters].[Select View]='Director' THEN[Drct Full Nm]
ELSEIF 
[Parameters].[Select View]='Manager' THEN [Mgr Full Nm]
ELSEIF
[Parameters].[Select View]='Designer' THEN [Designer_new]
END

The parameter value selections ('Director' and 'Manager') are as-is dimensions from data and show correct values on selection. It would be great if someone could point out the error in my solution. Thank you in advance.

Just some troubleshooting things to try: Check that everything is NULL if you remove your "ELSE" clause. Force the capitalization whether its upper or lower, so CONTAINS(TRIM(lower([Role])),"designer") . Also try right clicking [Designer_new] and converting to a dimension.
